# Unity Editor: check if OnDestroy() method is called because the scene is closing

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

There are 2 cases when `OnDestroy()` is triggered in the Editor (the class should be marked with `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute):

1. When the scene is closing and all objects are destroyed.
2. When an object is deleted from the scene.

Is it possible to differentiate these two cases within `OnDestroy()`? I tried to subscribe to `EditorSceneManager.sceneClosing` to set the flag and then use it in `OnDestroy()` but this event didn't work. Are there any other options?

Comment: Is this in Play Mode? `Unity.Editor.EditorSceneManager` is for the editor

Comment: Why do you need it, maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: I have waypoints, each can have multiple connections to others. When a waypoint is removed from the scene all the connections to it (from other waypoints) have to be removed too. The only way to know that an object is being removed, I guess, is `OnDestroy`. But it could be also triggered when the scene is closing in which case it doesn't mean "removing object" and no connection should be deleted.

Comment: Actually, I've already found a different way: connections are checked each time a new waypoint is added, but this logic looks awkward and this leads to redundant calculations every time a new object is created or just some of its properties are changed.

Comment: I might have found a way using `EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged`. If you tell me how you use your waypoints (are they all root-objects or children of a specific gameobject, do you maybe even have a manager for them? How do you store the connections (list?)) I might be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: @yes they were root-objects but now they all are put inside a rooted object named "_WAYPOINTS" which is created automatically when a new waypoint is added to the scene. I had some thoughts to rely on this object to understand whether the card is unloaded or not using the fact that a parent is destroyed before its children but it didn't seem possible since this object could be deleted manually as well.

Comment: I don't use a manager for them, a waypoint prefab can be added to the scene or an existing waypoint can be duplicated on the scene and the `Waypoint` class has a static field `SortedDictionary<int, Waypoint> _allWaypoints` to keep all the existing waypoint.
Yes, they have `List<Waypoint>`. When one is added to the scene it's automatically connected to the previous one but it's also possible to change these connections (list) via Inspector. When it's changed `OnValidate` is called where this list is checked for empty objects which are removed.

Comment: Now I've made optimization: I check if `OnDestroy()` is called for a waypoint but it hasn't been triggered for the parent container then this event is considered as removing a waypoint from the scene. But as I said it's not 100% reliable since a waypoint still can be moved from the parent to the root or any other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a hacky hackjob, there is lot of room for improvement depending on how exactly your waypoints are layed out and know about eachother.
If a connection is always mutual (means waypoint A is connected to B and B is connected to A) you could add the connections of the deleted waypoint in the `OnDestroy()` method, which would allow you to only check needed waypoints ^^

```cs
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public static class WaypointCleanup
{
    static Scene lastActiveScene;

    static WaypointCleanup() {
        lastActiveScene = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged += CheckAllWaypointsForNullConnections;
    }

    static void CheckAllWaypointsForNullConnections() {
        if(lastActiveScene.Equals(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene())) 
        {
            //Here be room for improvement, but if you want to check all
            //waypoints that could be child of everything, the only other way
            //I can currently think of would be to somehow register which
            //waypoints have to be checked from the OnDestroy method of the
            //waypoint class.
            if (Waypoint.NeedsCleanUp)
            {
                foreach (var waypoint in Waypoint.AllWaypoints.Values) 
                {
                    waypoint.ConnectedWaypoints.RemoveAll(item => !item);
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            lastActiveScene = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        }

        Waypoint.NeedsCleanUp = false;
    }
}
#endif
```

Above works with this.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Waypoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly SortedDictionary<int, Waypoint> AllWaypoints = new SortedDictionary<int, Waypoint>(); // The relevance of the list is controlled by the logic of the `Waypoint` class.
    public static bool NeedsCleanUp = false;
    public List<Waypoint> ConnectedWaypoints = new List<Waypoint>();

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (!IsEditor)
            return;

        NeedsCleanUp = true;
        // Other logic...
    }

    private bool IsEditor
    {
        get { return !Application.isPlaying; }
    }
}
```

Hope you can make something useful out of it. It's only meant as example for where you could hook into, so use with care, currently this goes over all waypoints and checks all connections against null.

Edit:
The above seems to work in whatever folder, I forgot to put it into some special Editor folder.

Comment: I think it will work, thanks! I would ask everyone who reads this to vote for [this issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/editorscenemanager-sceneclosing-and-sceneclosed-callbacks-are-not-called-when-switching-between-scenes) since if the `EditorSceneManager.sceneClosing` event worked the logic of the solution would be way simpler.

Comment: The callbacks are not completely broken though, if you open/close/create a scene from the SceneManager directly they are indeed called. Its kinda inconsistent though I agree. Gave it my vote, but given its only just 6 votes now, I doubt it will be fixed soon ^^

Comment: No, it also works in the editor, but only if you use the EditorSceneManager to open/close scenes. If you just switch a scene by doubleclicking nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited your code, it's waiting to be reviewed.

Comment: Idk if that was really necessary, I think it conveyed the general idea before aswell, but ok. I only edited in the static NeedsCleanUp field since you forgot it ^^

Answer (score 7):

A bit of an old question but it's the first result in Google so I thought I might share my approach.

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    if(gameObject.scene.isLoaded) //Was Deleted
    {

    }
    else //Was Cleaned Up on Scene Closure
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! This should be in the docs for OnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

## Use the [`SceneManager.sceneUnloaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneUnloaded.html) event

You can use a new component and attach it to objects you want to track this information from

```
public class CheckForOnSceneUnloaded : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool wasDestroyedOnSceneUnloaded = false;

    void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneUnloaded += OnSceneUnloaded;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneUnloaded -= OnSceneUnloaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneUnloaded(Scene current)
    {
        wasDestroyedOnSceneUnloaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @yes `EditorSceneManager` inherits from `SceneManager`. Would it not be correct to use that event?

Comment: Seems like neither callback of either Manager gets called in Editor if you dont load the scene from an editor script (and subscribe to from there). Just having a gameobject with a component with [ExecuteInEditMode] in the hierarchy does not seem to cut it. Or maybe its just me doing it wrong which is totally an option ^^